# Selenium when reconnecting, the site blocks the connection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I connect to https://coinsniper.net using undetected-chromedriver and profile to save the session. But when I reconnect, the site blocks the connection. Any advice would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService    
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time
import os

path_to_dir = r'{}\User'.format(os.getcwd())
path_to_driver = os.path.abspath('chromedriver.exe')

options = uc.ChromeOptions()

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path_to_driver, use_subprocess=True, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), user_data_dir = path_to_dir)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
    "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win64",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://coinsniper.net")
time.sleep(10)
driver.get("https://coinsniper.net")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reconnect"?  Do you mean the second call to `driver.get()`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "blocks the connection"?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I mean the second call to driver.get() and the site gives the error Sorry, you have been blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a different user profile.
When reconnection, try using a different user profile to avoid being detected and blocked  by the website. You can achieve this by creating a new user data directory for each session and providing it as the `user_data_dir` argument when initializing the `undetected-chromedriver`. Make sure to store cookies and other session data within the user data directory.

Comment: So for each session a new undiscovered chromedriver with its own directory is initialized?

Comment: Yes. Correct. You need to create new user data directory for selenium chrome driver.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, you've helped me out

Comment: Why does it work?